# Is there any Tcl package/add-on that handles named arguments?

Tags: tcl, parameter-passing

In Python, Ruby 2.0, Perl 6, and some hardware description languages, one can use named arguments. See this [example](https://docs.perl6.org/language/objects#Roles). This makes the code more readable, easy to maintain, etc. Is there a way of getting it done/extension, in TCL 8.6, other than using a dictionary as a workaround?

Comment: I think there is some code for this on the wiki,  but I think most of us just find it far too convenient to use a dict or an array if named arguments are desired to bother with adding more rules to argument handling.

Answer (score 2):

In 8.6, use a dictionary parsed from `args`. The `dict merge` command can help:

```
proc example args {
    if {[llength $args] % 2} {
        return -code error "wrong # args: should be \"example ?-abc abc? ?-def def?\""
    }
    set defaults {
        -abc 123
        -def 456
    }
    set args [dict merge $defaults $args]
    set abc [dict get $args -abc]
    set def [dict get $args -def]
    puts "abc=$abc, def=$def"
}

example;                       # abc=123, def=456
example -abc 789;              # abc=789, def=456
example -def 789;              # abc=123, def=789
example -def 246 -abc 135;     # abc=135, def=246
```

You can go further than that with verifying (the `tcl::prefix` command can help) but it's a lot more work and doesn't buy you a lot more in production code. Not that that has [stopped people from trying](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10702).

There are two proposals to add full named argument handling
([TIP #457](https://core.tcl.tk/tips/doc/trunk/tip/457.md), [TIP #479](https://core.tcl.tk/tips/doc/trunk/tip/479.md)) to 8.7 at the moment, but I'm not sure that either have really gained traction. (The problem from my perspective is the extra runtime cost that has to be borne by code that *doesn't* volunteer to support named arguments. There might be other issues too, such as disagreement over preferred syntax; I've not paid so much attention to that as I'm still fretting over the performance implications in a pretty hot piece of code.)

Comment: Arrays also work. `array set` the defaults first, then `array set` the real arguments.

Comment: There is an extra `]` at the end of `puts "abc=$abc, def=$def"]` (and edits need to have 6 characters...)

Answer (score 0):

There is an entire page on the tcler's wiki that discusses named arguments: http://wiki.tcl.tk/10702

You can do it yourself with a little creativity. There are several mechanisms that allow you to do this:

1. procs can define other procs
2. proc behave just like a proc (the function definition system is not a syntax, it is a function call)
3. procs can use the `args` argument instead of positional parameter and manually process the list of arguments
4. you can execute code in any parent stack frame using `uplevel`
5. you can pull variables from any parent stack frame using `upvar`
6. everything is a string!

etc.

I'm not sure I've listed all the possible mechanisms.

My personal implementation of this idea is optproc: http://wiki.tcl.tk/20066

The implementation itself is quite simple:

```
proc optproc {name args script} {
    proc $name args [
        string map [list ARGS $args SCRIPT $script] {
            foreach var {ARGS} {
                set [lindex $var 0] [lindex $var 1]
            }
            foreach {var val} $args {
                set [string trim $var -] $val
            }
            SCRIPT
        }
    ]
}
```

I basically used string manipulation (`string map`) to directly insert the function body (`$script`) into the defined function without any substitutions etc. This is to avoid any `$` or `[]` from being processed. There are many ways to do this but my go-to tool is `string map`.

This is similar to Donald's answer except for two things:

1. I don't transform `args` into a `dict` instead I manually process `args` and declare each local variable in a loop.
2. This is a meta solution. Instead of processing args I created another function (syntax) to create a function that processes args.

Usage (stolen from Donald's answer) would be:

```
optproc example {abc def} {
    puts "abc=$abc, def=$def"
}
```

But note that my solution is not the only solution. There are many ways to do this limited only by creativity.